# How to downsample timeseries/vectors to a constant length in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I am looking for a generalizable function that down sample any timeseries/vecotr to a constant length using any of pandas methods like rolling/sliding windows, resampling or ... but i want to define the number of new samples

For example, three independent series/ simply arrays as follows:

```
 t1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,6,5,4,3,2,2])
 t2 = pd.Series([2,3,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
 ts = pd.Series([10,14,18,19,20,22,23,25,27,34,37,41,51,67,69,73,75,82,88,89,90,100,110])
```

i would like to summarize/downsample each of above vectors/timeseries to a vector/Series of length 10.

Comment: What you show here are lists, a Series has both an index and values. What does `t1 = [1,2,3]` represent in terms of time and values?

Comment: time indexes are not applicable here, let's say we have sequence of numbers in columns these are values that come in certain order, but different length i want to have to downsample each of them to 10 observation in each column

Comment: Then please provide the exact expected output for clarity

Comment: They are independent of each other actually but just to give some idea i said there can be columns of a dataframes

Comment: OK, so what should be the output for `t1` assuming 10 values in the output?

Comment: I made some edit to the question, output would be a downsampled version of t1 without losing too much information

Comment: I'm sorry but "a downsampled version of t1" is not explicit. It looks like you don't really know what you want. It's not possible to program something without a clear logic.

Comment: I know what i want and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html does that exactly.

Comment: Then why don't you provide the requested output?

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you mention two different approaches summarizing and downsampling. The approach of summarizing drastically varies on your use case.

Summarizing:

You want a list of size **N** (10 in your example) and the lists are at least of size **N** to summarize.

- If the list is less than or equal to **N** elements, then return the same list.
- Otherwise you will need to do some form of summarizing. The problem here is that there are many different metrics for summarizing data and they vary based on the data you are providing. A naive approach here would be to perform a rolling average and then remove the similar values. Then repeat until you have only **N** elements.

Downsampling:

In the case of downsampling, you can use the `sample` method ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)). The method takes an optional parameter **N** - the number of items from axis to return. You will need to consider the case where the list is less than **N**. But a generic method for this could look like:

```py
def downsample(series, n):
  return series.sample(n)
```

*Note: the series is the series of data to downsample e.g. your `t1` and `n` is the sample size. Since we are not replacing, if the series is less than size `n` then an error is thrown.*